# How to hide certain fields on the User Edit form in Drupal?

Tags: forms, drupal, hook, hook-form-alter

So I have three types of users - admin, LA admin and users. I am trying to set it up so that admins and LA admins cannot edit the username, password and timezone for users. I am talking about the default user edit form for admins and the form ID is "user-profile-form".

I have created a custom module but this doesn't seem to be working. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Even the var_dump does not seem to be outputting. I have cleared the cache and verified that the module is enabled.

```
 function profile_change_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id === 'user-profile-form') {
       var_dump ($form);

       hide($form['account']['pass']);
       hide($form['account']['current_pass_required_values']);
       hide($form['account']['current_pass']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead make them disabled, that makes sense!

Answer (score 6):

If you use `hide()` you will remove the field, but hide is more for "delaying" field rendering... Like you hide it, but then (in template file) you print it at some other place.
Because, if you don't print it later it won't be rendered in the page, won't be saved, if it's mandatory you'll get validation error and so on.

If you want to hide it, so user can not see it but you want the form to keep previous value of the field use something like:

```
$form['field_yourfield']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

and if you want it to be visible, but disabled (user can't change it's value) then:

```
$form['field_yourfield']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you module name is **PROFILE_CHANGE** & so that you have used it in the format of `hook_form_alter()`, where you have replaced `hook` with your module name `profile_change`.

You have put **3 '='** sign where you are giving condition to check form id, which is `user-profile-form`. I have put simple equal sign which is **'=='** & it's working.

```
function profile_change_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'user-profile-form') {
       hide($form['account']['pass']);
       hide($form['account']['current_pass_required_values']);
       hide($form['account']['current_pass']);
    }
}
```

Don't use `var_dump()`, You should always use [DEVEL](https://drupal.org/project/devel) & check the output of `$form` like `dpm($form)` just after your hook function for form alter. This will give you all info about form, where ever you have a form on your page.

```
function profile_change_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form);
}
```

Comment: DEVEL is not the solution to everything, and can even be the worst pick for debugging!

Answer (score 3):

Actually I just had to change `user-profile-form` to `user_profile_form` in my code for it to work. For some reason, drupal requires underscores.

Comment: The `$form_id` is the ID of the form as taken from its PHP function name, not the HTML ID (which isn't guaranteed to be consistent). That's why it contains underscores and not hyphens when you alter the form

Comment: "for some reason" is because dashes and underscores are not equivalent strings. The markup Drupal outputs contains dashes, but internally it uses underscores. You can find the Form ID by viewing your source and finding `input[name="form_id"]` and using that exact value. Try running this jQuery snippet in your browser console on any Drupal admin form page: `jQuery('input[name="form_id"]').val()`